# what does callbacks option in ssh2 stream wrapper do?

Tags: php, stream, libssh2

http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ssh2.php

One of the context options is callbacks but it doesn't have a description next to it. In fact it's the only context option that doesn't have a description next to it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually callbacks are user functions that can be called by api for errors, async IO and similar. Better definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

There's a codesnip [here](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10369507-RESOLVED-Moving-files-to-and-from-remote-server-over-SSH) that uses them in this fashion.

Maybe more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php) too.

Comment: Ah...  interesting. I didn't realize callbacks were a parameter in ssh2_connect as well. That does indeed answer that. Thanks!